# Rails CollectionProxy randomly inserts in wrong order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm seeing some weird behaviour in my models, and was hoping someone could shed some light on the issue.

```
# user model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_and_belongs_to_many :attended_events

  def attend(event)
    self.attended_events << event
  end
end

# helper method in /spec-dir
def attend_events(host, guest)
  host.events.each do |event|
    guest.attend(event)
  end
end
```

This, for some reason inserts the event with id **2** before the event with id **1**, like so:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Event id: 2, name: "dummy-event", user_id: 1>, #<Event id: 1, name: "dummy-event", user_id: 1>
```

But, when I do something seemlingly random - like for instance change the `attend_event` method like so:

```
def attend_event(event)
  self.attended_events << event
  p self.attended_events # random puts statement
end
```

It gets inserted in the correct order.

```
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Event id: 1, name: "dummy-event", user_id: 1>, #<Event id: 2, name: "dummy-event", user_id: 1>
```

What am I not getting here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you specify an order on the association, associations are unordered when they are retrieved from the database (the generated sql won't have an order clause so the database is free to return things in whatever order it wants)

You can specify an order by doing (rails 4.x upwards)

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :attended_events, scope: -> {order("something")}
```

or, on earlier versions

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :attended_events, :order => "something"
```

When you've just inserted the object you may see a different object - here you are probably seeing the loaded version of the association, which is just an array (wrapped by the proxy)